# How to place all floats (tables in particular) at a certain point in the document

Tags: tables, floats, appendices

I would like to place all of the tables in the document at the end but before the bibliography generated by `biblatex` and the notes printed by `endnotes`.

In other words, I'd like to collect the tables and output them all in their section using something like

```
\printtables
```

or

```
\printfloats
```

It seems to me I can't use `endfloat` because it prints the tables on a new page and literally at the end of the entire document (ie after the bibliography and the end notes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [endfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package, loading it in the following way:

```
\usepackage[tablesonly,nomarkers]{endfloat}
```

and use

```
\processdelayedfloats
```

before the bibliography or at the point where you want your tables to appear. If you don't want every table to start in a new page, you can redefine `\efloatseparator` (defaul value: `\clearpage`); something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[tablesonly,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\renewcommand\efloatseparator{\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
text \\
text \\
text \\
text  \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test delayed table}
\end{table}
\section{test}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
text \\
text \\
text \\
text  \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Another test delayed table}
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{a} test
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

And the last page of the document produced:

[image]

Comment: ...and regarding the "it prints the tables on a new page" stuff: You can redefine `\efloatseparator` to change that, see `endfloat` doc, section 7. (No need to redefine `\clearpage`)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: you're right. I've incorporated your siggestion into my answer. Thanks!